# @Published as a function argument with Swift Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I want to be able to pass a reference to a @Published property in as a parameter so that other objects can use, edit, and view the data on the property, and I want to do it while keeping the functionality of Property wrappers in Swift

Here is my example. I create a MainStore object. It has an array of names which is @Published. I can use this object all across my app, I can change the data in `names` and anywhere that subscribes will get the update.

```
class MainStore {
    @Published var names: [String]
    
    init(names: [String]) {
        self.names = names
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a second Store. This has a bit of additional functionality, and it needs to be more focused but I want it to reference the `names` property from the MainStore. When MainStore.names is updated, I want SecondStore.names to be updated as well. When SecondStore.names is updated, I want MainStore.names to be updated as well.

```
class SecondStore {
    
    @Published var names: [String]
    
    init(@Published names: [String]) {
        self.names = names
    }
}
```

I want the syntax of a @Published property wrapper as well

eg `SecondStore.names.append("Billy")` and `SecondStore.$names.sink() { }`

Is there a way to do this, if not what is the recommended practice to accomplish my general direction?

Comment: That seems like a roundabout way of achieving what a shared object would achieve.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the `MainStore` object to the `SecondStore` and then *listen* to the changes made to the `mainStore.names` property.

```
class MainStore {
    @Published var names: [String]

    init(names: [String]) {
        self.names = names
    }
}
```

```
class SecondStore {
    @Published var names: [String] = []

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(mainStore: MainStore) {
        // listen to the `$names` publisher
        mainStore.$names
            // all `@Published` properties must be updated on the `main` thread
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            // assign received value to self.names
            .sink { [weak self] in
                self?.names = $0
            }
            // keep it in memory so it won't be cancelled
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

---

Note that in the `.sink` part there is a possibility of a strong reference cycle.

This is why `[weak self]` is used. You can read more here: [Weak Self in Swift Made Easy: What it is and why it’s needed](https://matteomanferdini.com/swift-weak-self/)